# JQuery Tools Scrollable: next/prev buttons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using JQuery Tools' Scrollable in a fashion very similar to: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/site-navigation.html

Because of the way I've got it on my page, I need to allow users to click buttons to advance horizontally within each vertical. The current tags:

```
<a class="prev browse left"></a>

<a class="next browse right"></a>
```

advance the slides both horizontally and vertically, resulting in a diagonal movement that changes vertical AND horizontal. How can I restrict their behavior to just moving horizontally?